# select option based on all values in an input

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple reservation form. In this form, I have two input box and I change number of each room based on value of input hidden with class name "rooms", moreover there is another input that shows

> numbers like this:  1 ,8*1 ,11

the first digit shows a count of person and the second digit after comma shows the age of that person in the first room.

I separated first and second rooms with a star between them. the digits after star shows count and age of each person in the second room as well.

my question is how can I use these digits for selecting my select boxes?

for example, I want to use the first digit for select box child. if that number was 1. i would choose 1 in first room for my child . also second number for age of first child in my first room and etc.

I wrote the below code with function fillchild but it does not work .

here is my snippet :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#rooms').val($('.rooms').val());
  $('#rooms').change()
})

$("#rooms").change(function() {

  countRoom = $(this).val();

  $(".numberTravelers").empty()
  for (i = 1; i <= countRoom; i++) {
    $(".numberTravelers").css("width", "100%").append('<div class="countRoom"><div class="numberOfRooms">room' + i + '</div><div class="col-xs-4">child<select name="childcount" class="childcount" onchange="childAge(this)"><option value="0"> 0 </option><option value="1"> 1 </option> <option value="2"> 2 </option></select></div><div class="selectAge col-xs-4"></div><input type="hidden" name="_root.rooms__' + i + '.childcountandage" class="childcountandage"/></div>')

  }
});

function childAge(a) {
  $(a).each(function() {
    age = $(a).val();

    $(a).closest(".countRoom").find(".selectAge").empty();
    for (var j = 1; j <= age; j++) {
      $(a).closest(".countRoom").css("width", "100%").find(".selectAge").append('<div class="age"><label>child age' + j + '</label><select name="childage" class="childage form-control"><option value="1">till 1 year</option><option value="2">1-2 year</option><option value="3">2-3 year</option><option value="4">3-4 year</option></select></div>');
    }
    fillchild();
  });
}

function fillchild() {
  var childCounts = $('.childage').val().split(',');
  var ageCounts = $('.childage').val().split('*');
  childCounts.forEach((childage, index) => {
    var selectname = '_root.rooms__' + (index + 1) + '.childcountandage';
    var selectElement = $('input[name="' + selectname + '"]');
    if (selectElement.length > 0) {
      $(selectElement).val(childage);
    }

  })
}
```

```css
.numberOfRooms {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.childage {
  background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="researchii">
  <input type="hidden" class="rooms" value="2" />
  <input type="text" class="childage" value="1 ,8*1 ,11" readonly />
  <div class="col-xs-4">
    <span class="itemlable">rooms: </span>
    <select name="rooms" id="rooms">
    <option value="1" class="btn2"> 1 </option>
    <option value="2" class="btn2"> 2 </option>
   </select>
  </div>
  <div class="numberTravelers">
    <div class="countRoom">
      <div class="col-xs-4">
        <span class="itemlable">child</span>
        <select name="childcount" class="childcount" onChange="childAge(this)">
      <option value="0"> 0 </option>
      <option value="1"> 1 </option>
      <option value="2"> 2 </option>
     </select>
      </div>
      <div class="selectAge col-xs-4"></div>
      <input type="hidden" name="_root.rooms__1.childcountandage" class="childcountandage" />
    </div>
  </div>


</div>
```

Comment: You want to auto select the dropdown. Right?

Comment: `it does not work`. Please specify what doesn't work. There is error in console, variable name is `selectname` but you have used `selectName`.

Comment: I do not see the `age` select box. There is only select box for `child`. Do you need to get the selected value for `child` only at the moment?

Comment: @AnkitAgarwal please select a child . if you select a child you can see age of that child.

Comment: @Lalit yes  i want to auto select them

Comment: Cool. I will have a look @inaz

Comment: @AnkitAgarwal did you see that?

Comment: i am busy with that .

Comment: @inaz have a look at the answer. I have included the case where child is 2 or 3 instead of 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have made it dynamic so that it still works for 2 child with age 3 and 4. You can see that example below.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#rooms').val($('.rooms').val());
  $('#rooms').change()
})

$("#rooms").change(function() {

  countRoom = $(this).val();

  $(".numberTravelers").empty()
  for (i = 1; i <= countRoom; i++) {
    $(".numberTravelers").css("width", "100%").append('<div class="countRoom"><div class="numberOfRooms">room' + i + '</div><div class="col-xs-4">child<select name="childcount" class="childcount" onchange="childAge(this)"><option value="0"> 0 </option><option value="1"> 1 </option> <option value="2"> 2 </option></select></div><div class="selectAge col-xs-4"></div><input type="hidden" name="_root.rooms__' + i + '.childcountandage" class="childcountandage"/></div>')

  }
  fillchild();
});

var ageGlobal ='';
function childAge(a) {
  $(a).each(function() {
    age = $(a).val();
    ageGlobal = ageGlobal.split(',');
    $(a).closest(".countRoom").find(".selectAge").empty();
    for (var j = 1; j <= age; j++) {
      $(a).closest(".countRoom").css("width", "100%").find(".selectAge").append('<div class="age"><label>child age' + j + '</label><select name="childage" class="childage form-control"><option value="1">till 1 year</option><option value="2">1-2 year</option><option value="3">2-3 year</option><option value="4">3-4 year</option></select></div>');
      var ageVal = ageGlobal[j-1] || "1";
      //set the value of age dropdown
      $(a).closest(".countRoom")
      .find("select[name='childage']:eq("+(j-1)+")")
      .val(ageVal);
    }
  });
  //reset ageGlobal so that it works when child is changed
  ageGlobal = "1";
}

function fillchild() {
  var roomChildAge = $('.childage').val().split('*');
  roomChildAge.forEach((childAge, index) => {
   //find the child dropdown for the room
    var childElement = $($('.countRoom')[index]).find('.childcount');
    //element for child exist
    if (childElement.length > 0) {
      //get the child and age values using substring
      var childCount;
      //when there is no child and its age
      if(childAge.trim()==="0"){
         childCount = "0";  
         ageGlobal ='';
      }else{
         childCount = childAge.substring(0, childAge.indexOf(','));
         ageGlobal = childAge.substring(childAge.indexOf(',')+1, childAge.length);
      }
      $(childElement).val(childCount.trim());
      //trigger change eveny so that age select box is pre-selected
      $(childElement).trigger('change');
    }

  })
}
```

```css
.numberOfRooms {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.childage {
  background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="researchii">
  <input type="hidden" class="rooms" value="2" />
  <input type="text" class="childage" value="2 ,3,4*0" readonly />
  <div class="col-xs-4">
    <span class="itemlable">rooms: </span>
    <select name="rooms" id="rooms">
    <option value="1" class="btn2"> 1 </option>
    <option value="2" class="btn2"> 2 </option>
   </select>
  </div>
  <div class="numberTravelers">
    <div class="countRoom">
      <div class="col-xs-4">
        <span class="itemlable">child</span>
        <select name="childcount" class="childcount" onChange="childAge(this)">
      <option value="0"> 0 </option>
      <option value="1"> 1 </option>
      <option value="2"> 2 </option>
     </select>
      </div>
      <div class="selectAge col-xs-4"></div>
      <input type="hidden" name="_root.rooms__1.childcountandage" class="childcountandage" />
    </div>
  </div>


</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much ! you made my day. :)

Comment: I am glad to help you. Remember for more issues and help.

Comment: i faced with a problem. in this case I do not have any child in second room , the value of my input returns somethig like this : 2 ,3,4*0. how can i say if my value was something like this choose 0 in my selectbox instead of choose nothing in selectbox of childeren?

Comment: You can have a condition for 0 that will simply skip everything and work normally.

Comment: excuse me . I tried but i could not add this condition. . where should i define this condition?

Comment: I am busy today and i might not help you soon. Is this urgent to you?

Comment: oh i get stuck with this issue in the company. can you please help me whenever u had time enough ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162311/discussion-between-ankit-agarwal-and-inaz).